# Why my ObjectSpace.dump is not complete?

Tags: ruby, heap-memory

I have a behavior that I don't understand with ObjectSpace.dump_all method : I need to close my ruby console to get a no truncated result.

How to reproduce :

1) Open an irb console (tested with 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0)

```
$ irb
```

2) run the following script :

```
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start
dump = ObjectSpace.dump_all(output: :file)
cmd = "tail -1 #{dump.path}"
# => "tail -1 /var/folders/d2/xs3bvd7j1xb8t4bp188bbwc80000gn/T/rubyheap20160215-45059-6djhip.json"
`#{cmd}`
# => "{\"address\":\"0x7fb0822a7df0\", \"type\":\"NODE\", \"frozen\":true, \"node_type\":\"NODE_ARRAY\", \"references\":[\"0"
```

3) In another console, run the same tail command :

```
$ tail -1 /var/folders/d2/xs3bvd7j1xb8t4bp188bbwc80000gn/T/rubyheap20160215-45059-6djhip.json
{"address":"0x7fb0822a7df0", "type":"NODE", "frozen":true, "node_type":"NODE_ARRAY", "references":["0%
```

4) At the step we clearly can see that the dump does not finish by a valid json. Ok, next step : close the irb console and redo :

```
$ tail -1 /var/folders/d2/xs3bvd7j1xb8t4bp188bbwc80000gn/T/rubyheap20160215-45059-6djhip.json
{"address":"0x7fb0822a7fa8", "type":"OBJECT", "class":"0x7fb08216ba68", "ivars":3, "references":["0x7fb0822a7f08"], "memsize":40, "flags":{"wb_protected":true, "old":true, "long_liv
ed":true, "marked":true}}
```

Now, the file is a valid Json. 
But why it's mandatory to close the irb console to get the full export?

Comment: it could be that the file is not closed.

Comment: You're right, the file is still open : it's appear on lsof | grep my_file.json.

Comment: Thank's for your comment, i will search this way : Why this method does not close the file.
(Not related : I don't understand the downvote on my question and I really don't understand people that downvote without response).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, dump_all return an open File object.
After a dump_all, you have to close the file :

```
dump = ObjectSpace.dump_all(output: :file)
dump.close
```

Thx Uri Agassi